# Get an array of numbers between A and B?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to generate an array of values between A and B, but not finding any easy functions to do so.

```
GenerateArray(1,5) -> {1,2,3,4,5}

B1=8
B2=11
GenerateArray(B1,B2) -> {8,9,10,11}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the output to be? Do you want the output in a cell or do you mean within Apps Script?

Comment: I was intending this to be used in a cell

Comment: How did this go for you?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the sequence function.

```
=SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,1,B1,1)
```

`B2-B1+1` will give you the number of rows needed.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

#### There is no specific spreadsheet function for that, but you can use [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions).

This does involve some JavaScript and Apps Script, so you may want to look at the [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials) if you want to learn more about it.

#### Your example

1. In your Spreadsheet, open the script editor.
2. Paste this code:

```js
function GenerateArray(a, b) {
  // Using a simple JavaScript array to build the output
  let output = [];

  // For loop to go through all the numbers adding them to the output
  for (let i = a; i <= b; i++){
    output.push(i)
  }

  // Building the output as a string to add the curly brackets
  output = "{" + output.toString() + "}"

  // Returning final output
  return output
}
```

3. Save the script.
4. Run it as if it was a normal spreadsheet function.

This is what it looks like in action:

[image]

[image]

Note that the function does not return a JavaScript array, which are denoted by square brackets. It returns a plain text "string". If you returned a JavaScript array from the function instead of a string, then the result would expand into adjacent columns.

So if you deleted this line:

```js
output = "{" + output.toString() + "}"
```

The result you would get would be:

[image]

Yet for that you might just be better off using the [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) formula:

```
=SEQUENCE(1, 10)
```

#### Equivalent with native spreadsheet functions

```
="{" & JOIN(",",SEQUENCE(1,10)) & "}"
```

This will do the same as the custom function above but only using native spreadsheet functions. It makes use of [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077) to string together numbers from `SEQUENCE` with a comma in between them (though you can change this), and then concatenates curly braces on it with the `&` operator.

[image]

#### References and Further Reading

- [Spreadsheet Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions)
- [Apps Script Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)
- [For Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)
- [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)
- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)